# Repeatedly seach site on google

Tags: seo, search

If i search my site repeatedly on google or other search engine by different keyword and click on result for my site, is effect on my seo in long time? my site rank increased ? or search result rank?

Answer (score 2):

Click-through has always been in huge debate and no one actually knows for sure how much influence it holds, because its one of thousands of Google's secrets.

But what I can tell you is that Google will know its you doing the clicking therefore you are not as a treated as unique visitor. They know its you through cookies and your ip address.

Comment: Okay. This may sound weird. But for a long while I conducted an experiment by clicking once daily on a few specific domain/performance junk SEO websites after searching my domain. I would see them rise in the SERPs for my domain name. Then I would pick a few other saps and watch them rise and the others fall. I would search my domain name with and without site: just to see what is important and somewhere I thought I would have a bit of fun. So CTR even a small one for a search that is specific enough can move a page in the SERPs. I would not recommend this for you own site of course.

Comment: It may just seem that it does, rankings can drop and flux daily without any visible reason other than the fact you been clicking but may have nothing to do with it at all. I'd say clicks on a mass scale could have an influence, especially for 'BRANDS'.

Comment: I was picking a page that should never rank on SERP page 23 (or so) and watch it move to page 2 or 1. Then when I stopped it would go back to page 18 or 19 or whatever. I originally was studying certain web markets and how they make money. I hate most of these sites so it was a bit of stupid fun. BTW- I would sometimes check SERP performance from outside of my computers and network just to see and sure enough, it did make a difference. It was just one page though and it took one daily click over a long period. So it was nothing earth shattering. I just found it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, clicking on a SERP result can change ranking. No, its not that easy and results won't stick [permanently] by spam clicking it via 1 endpoint because Google has very advanced abuse/proxy/tracking abilities. True you may see the SERP rise, but it is probably introvertive and could be due to you being logged into G+, G account, your browser signature, device key, past behavior, current behavior, or as triggered locality to another mysterious UID assimilation.

Every link presented in Google serps routes via their `google.com/url` router, redirect, masking, & insignts engine. To see this, right click a link, copy the url. Then paste it and deconstruct. For this example, I searched for **bananas** and copied the router url for the 4th result.

Here is the deconstructed URi:

```
https://www.google.com/url
?sa=t (unknown)
&rct=j (unknown)
&q= (this is the query, missing via HTTPS searches)
&esrc=s (this is the secure identifier)
&source=web (since I came via google.com)
&cd=4 (this is the SERP position of the link I clicked)
&cad=rja (looks to be an affiliate app style acronym)
&uact=8 (looks like the Google account type)
&ved=0CDsQFjADahUKEwjAs6GE2eLGAhXDez4KHa_pAdE (unknown)
&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnutritiondata.self.com%2Ffacts%2Ffruits-and-fruit-juices%2F1846%2F2 (the target URL)
&ei=DDypVcD9KMP3-QGv04eIDQ (unknown)
&usg=AFQjCNFCrjlY8WC45YqAu4IbvWjvkZYPIg (unknown)
&bvm=bv.97949915,d.cWw (unknown)
```

So true, no one knows for sure whether Google counts clicks towards ranking. But, why would they track so much if it didn't affect SERP performance? I will go on a limb against all arguments and say: **Google absolutely uses click through data over time to mitigate ranking results.** The reason they never admit to it is because of the same reasons they don't admit to all the other SEO factors - It would cause a **** storm of operator anger, blackhat abuse, trojan client bots, etc. In their eyes it's better to just leave it in an air of mystery.

**EDIT 8-7-15:** [Stumbled onto this article](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/is-click-through-rate-a-ranking-signal) talking about various Google patents such as [US8938463](http://www.google.com/patents/US8938463) describing the predictability, reliability, and entity implications based on user intents->clicks. The abstract of the patent quite literally lays it out, although we still can only assume this behavior is present in Google search rank methods (emphasis is mine):

> The present disclosure includes systems and techniques relating to
>   ranking search results of a search query. In general, the subject
>   matter described in this specification can be embodied in a
>   computer-implemented method that includes: receiving multiple
>   features, **including a first feature indicative of presentation bias
>   that affects document result selection for search results presented in
>   a user interface of a document search service**; obtaining, based on the
>   multiple features, information regarding document result selections
>   for searches performed using the document search service; generating a
>   prior model using the information, the prior model representing a
>   background probability of document result selection given values of
>   the multiple features; and outputting the prior model to a ranking
>   engine for ranking of search results to reduce influence of the
>   presentation bias.